# the_excerpt() not working in custom archive

Tags: wp-query, loop, archives, excerpt

I have made a custom archive template which I want to display all the latest posts. I have managed to get this to work when searching for categories using archive.php fine.

However now I have created a page template for displaying the archive with the same code, get_excerpt() Is not working. Here is the function for excerpt in my function.php file

```
function add_excerpt_class( $excerpt ) {

if ( is_front_page() ){
    $excerpt = str_replace( "<p", "<p class=\"book-description hidden-md-down brown\"", $excerpt );
    return $excerpt;
} elseif ( is_archive() || is_page( 'blog' ) ){
    $excerpt = str_replace( "<p", "<p class=blog-extract", $excerpt );
    return $excerpt;
} else {
    $excerpt = str_replace( "<p", "<p class=blog-extract", $excerpt );
    return $excerpt;
}

}
```

This is my query (only in page template)

```
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 4,
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => false );

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>


            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php

                    include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-archive.php' ) );

                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            blogImages(<?php echo $post_number; ?>, <?php echo json_encode($archiveImgArray); ?>);
            </script>

        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

I've used include local template instead of get_template_part for a script and this works find in archive.php. In archive-content.php it's simply

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

the title(); works fine so what has gone wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

I've found a workaround.

```
$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $latest_post["ID"] );
$content = strip_tags($content);
$content = wp_trim_words($content);
```

and then just echo $content instead of the excerpt